# Ceiling Fan Remote Receiver

Tags: ceiling-fan

My ceiling Fan receiver will not fit in the ceiling where it is supposed to. Can I rewire and place the receiver on top of the motor instead? Will the transmitter still connect with the receiver? Will the motor get too hot and damage the Receiver if it sits atop the motor?

Comment: Post some pictures would help that show how it is packaged, what the top of the fan looks like, what voltage etc. Under what code requirements are there.

Comment: While you're [edit]ing your post to add the pics, include the make/model of the fan in question and indicate whether the remote came with the fan or if it's an add-on that you've purchased separately. If it's a separate remote, include the make/model of it, too.

Comment: With the Hunter fans the remote signals to the receiver/switch which is hard wired with wired  inputs (hot and neutral) and wired outputs (neutral, switched hot to fan, switched hot to light). So the receiver does not communicate wirelessly with the fan motor. If the fan has pull chain switches, the light switch must be on, and the fan pull chain switch must be on high speed, and these are left permanently in those positions.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of this situation?

Comment: You're gonna need a bigger boatXXXX  hole in the ceiling.  Do you even have a proper electrical box to mount the fan motor to?